# nearGeoPoint over 100 miles

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to sort my query results using the nearGeoPoint constraint. However, Parse docs mention a caveat that "Using the nearGeoPoint constraint will also limit results to within 100 miles."

How do I continue sorting results beyond the first 100 miles, especially if I have thousands of results that need to be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to try:

```
PFQuery whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles:
```

and set your withinMiles to > 100.

I can't guarantee it will work, but it's certainly worth a shot! Worst case scenario is will error out and you know the limitations of Parse for certain.

Comment: If it doesn't error out, it's a silent hard lock on the distance. I've run into this sort of problem before with Parse; sometimes they don't send you back an error message, they just hard lock a constraint and return per normal.